# How to stop css image slideshow at last image?

Tags: html, css

I have a slideshow with 3 images with different texts and I want to stop the autoplay at the last photo, so the last message/image will not fade out and dissapear. Here is the code:

HTML part:

```
<div class="slide-container">    
<img class="slide1" src="images/1banner.jpg">
<img class="slide2" src="images/2banner.jpg">
<img class="slide3" src="images/3banner.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
 .slide-container {
position: relative;
float: right;
height: 150px;
width: 950px;
background: url('banner-back2.jpg');
}

.slide-container img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 150px;
width: 950px; 
opacity: 0;
}

.slide1 { -webkit-animation: fade 12s;}
.slide2 { -webkit-animation: fade 12s 4s;}
.slide3 { -webkit-animation: fade 12s 8s;}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
0% { opacity: 0; }
10% { opacity: 1; }
20% { opacity: 1; }
30% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce a second fade-animation which stays visible and apply it to the last slide:

```
.slide-container {
position: relative;
float: right;
height: 150px;
width: 950px;
background: url('banner-back2.jpg');
}

.slide-container img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 150px;
width: 950px; 
opacity: 0;
}

.slide1 { -webkit-animation: fade 12s;}
.slide2 { -webkit-animation: fade 12s 4s;}
.slide3 { -webkit-animation: fade2 12s 8s; -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; }

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
0% { opacity: 0; }
10% { opacity: 1; }
20% { opacity: 1; }
30% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade2 {
0% { opacity: 0; }
10% { opacity: 1; }
100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works....I was wondering about that but I was setting the wrong opacity properties  :)

Comment: You can "accept" the answer if it answered your question :-)

Comment: Just a little extra touch: 

    .slide3 { 
        -webkit-animation: fade2 12s 8s; 
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
    }
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards makes sure the animation stops at the last frame, without it, the image would dissapear after 3 / 4 seconds

Comment: you're right, it dissapears after around 8 seconds. Now its good